# Need an efficient algorithm solve this kind of complex structure

Tags: java, c, algorithm, multidimensional-array

Problem Statement is :

Given 2 Dimensional array, print output for example

If 4 rows and 6 columns, output would be:

```
        1    2    3    4    5    6 
        16   17   18   19   20   7
        15   24   23   22   21   8
        14   13   12   11   10   9
```

I tried it is looking like square within square but when I attempted this problem, I put so many while and if loops but didn't got exact answer. If row and columns increases how to handle it?

This is **not** homework. I was learning solving complex structure so I need to understand it by some guidance.

Comment: In five minutes I could come up with at least ten different ways to do that.  You should be able to think of at least one way in a half an hour.

Comment: @VanDarg Yes but probably not this one if it isn't a classical school problem.

Comment: It'd be good if you told us the logic behind the array. It's clearly not a random array of numbers

Comment: A simple way : initialize an array and go from left to right, filling the cells on the way, until you find a "wall" or a filled cell, then turn and go on.

Comment: @HotLicks Can u suggest one idea for it

Comment: Those who put negative vote please take it back . Common guys i want to learn something from here what s the big deal .

Comment: I gave you an idea. Why aren't you coding now ?

Comment: @Rizvan - A small example of effort goes a long way. It's much easier for us to modify existing code than it is for us to generate our own.

Comment: @Rizvan: Are you allowed to populate the existing array? I'm thinking a simple 2D boolean array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what I came with.

Variables name may be upside/down, lot of thing to enhance, remove, modify but it was fun game.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 2;
        int y = 2;
        int idx = 1;
        int[][] array = new int[x][y];
        int yUpIdx = y-1;
        int yDownIdx = 0;
        int xLeftIdx = 0;
        int xRightIdx = x-1;


        while (idx < x*y) {
            for (int i = xLeftIdx; idx <= x*y && i <= xRightIdx; i++) {
                array[i][yDownIdx] = idx++;
            }
            yDownIdx++;
            for (int j = yDownIdx; idx <= x*y &&  j <= yUpIdx; j++) {
                array[xRightIdx][j] = idx++;
            }
            xRightIdx--;
            for (int i = xRightIdx; idx <= x*y &&  i>=xLeftIdx ; i--) {
                array[i][yUpIdx] = idx++;
            }
            yUpIdx--;
            for (int j = yUpIdx; idx <= x*y &&  j>=yDownIdx ; j--) {
                array[xLeftIdx][j] = idx++;
            }
            xLeftIdx++;
        }
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            for (int i = 0 ; i < x; i++) {
                if ((array[i][j]+"").length() < 2) System.out.print(" "); 
                System.out.print(array[i][j]+" ");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope I won't do anything more ;) A little work can't be bad. You got the drawing. Now take the picture.

Comment: Thanks dude :) i would see this idea

Answer (score 4):

It's a square spiral.
You can read a bout it here: 
http://metacpan.org/pod/Math::PlanePath::SquareSpiral

There's an explanation for the [formulas](http://metacpan.org/pod/Math%3a%3aPlanePath%3a%3aSquareSpiral#FORMULAS).

Comment: seriously ? you just need to substract i from N and you get the inverse.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution using the same "walk in a spiral" algo:

```
public class SpiralArray {
    private int[][] cells;
    private int rows;
    private int cols;

    private enum Direction {
        LEFT,
        DOWN,
        RIGHT,
        UP
    }

    public SpiralArray(int cols, int rows) {
        this.cols = cols;
        this.rows = rows;
        cells = new int[cols][rows];
        int count = 0;
        Direction direction = Direction.RIGHT;
        int x=0, y=0;
        while (count++ < cols*rows) {
            cells[x][y]=count;
            switch (direction) {
            case LEFT: 
                if ((--x<0) || (cells[x][y]>0)) {
                    y--;
                    x++;
                    direction = Direction.UP;
                }
                break;
            case RIGHT: 
                if ((++x==cols) || (cells[x][y]>0)) {
                    y++;
                    x--;
                    direction = Direction.DOWN;
                }
                break;
            case UP: 
                if ((--y<0) || (cells[x][y]>0)) {
                    x++;
                    y++;
                    direction = Direction.RIGHT;
                }
                break;
            case DOWN: 
                if ((++y==rows) || (cells[x][y]>0)) {
                    x--;
                    y--;
                    direction = Direction.LEFT;
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    int get(int i, int j) {
        return cells[i][j];
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int y=0; y<rows; y++) {
            for (int x=0; x<cols; x++) {
                sb.append(cells[x][y]).append("\t");
            }
            sb.append("\n");
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new SpiralArray(6, 4));
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1):

I hope this idea can get you started:

```
void solve2DArray(bool[][] 2DArray, int i, int j, int numMoves)
{                               
     2DArray[i][j] = true;   // Mark current position as visited
     // Perhaps a print statement here
     if(right is not visited and can move right)
       // move right
     else if(down is not visited and can move down)
       // move down
     // ...
     // ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd probably create an NxM integer array, initialized to zero.  Set `nextNumber` to 1, `position` to 0,0, and `direction` to `left-to-right`.  Check the `position` for being outside the array, and check the cell at `position` for zero. If `position` is OK and the cell is zero store `nextNumber` there and increment `nextNumber`.  Then, based on `direction`, increment `position`.

If the cell at `position` is non-zero, or one of the indices of `position` is < 0 or >= the array size, you need to change direction.  First back up `position` by 1, using the existing direction.  Then pick a new `direction` that is 90 degrees from the current value, increment `position`, and try again.

When you can't go any direction you're done -- print the array.

(Probably a few boundary conditions I mishandled above, but that's one basic algorithm.)

(Hint: Write a subroutine to increment/decrement `position` based on `direction`.)

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can just create a worm that travels through your array:

```
public class Worm {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[][] outArray = runWormRun(6, 4);
        printArray(outArray);
    }

    private static void printArray(int[][] outArray) {
        for (int j = 0; j < outArray[0].length; j++) {
            for (int i = 0; i < outArray.length; i++) {
                System.out.print(String.format("%02d ", outArray[i][j]));
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

    private static int[][] runWormRun(int w, int h) {
        int[][] output = new int[w][h];

        int counter = 0;
        int wormX = 0, wormY = 0;
        int minX = 0, maxX = w - 1, minY = 0, maxY = h - 1;
        int dirX = 0, dirY = 1;
        while (counter < w * h) {
            output[wormX][wormY] = ++counter;
            // let the worm walk
            wormX += dirX;
            wormY += dirY;
            // update direction of worm for next iteration
            if ((dirX != 0 && dirY != 1) && wormX == minX && wormY == minY) { // upper left border (and not yet rotated correctly
                dirX = 0; dirY = 1; minY++;
            }
            if ((dirX != -1 && dirY != 0) && wormX == maxX && wormY == minY) { // upper right border
                dirX = -1; dirY = 0; maxX--;
            }
            if ((dirX != 0 && dirY != -1) && wormX == maxX && wormY == maxY) { // lower right border
                dirX = 0; dirY = -1; maxY--;
            }
            if ((dirX != 1 && dirY != 0) && wormX == minX && wormY == maxY) { // lower left border
                dirX = 1; dirY = 0; minX++;
            }
        }
        return output;
    }
}
```

And yes, my worm travels in the other direction, because I want you to think a bit too and understand, what I was doing. Because I think that this is homework. (If that's true, would you please consider adding the "homework" tag to your question?)

EDIT: Ooops, does not exactly, what it should do. No time now, will look into that in the evening.

Comment: @VanDarg What else would that be... :D

Answer (score 1):

Another take:

```
public class Test {
  enum Dir {
    R(0,1), L(0,-1), D(1,0), U(-1,0);
    public final int rowd, cold;
    private Dir(int rowd, int cold) { this.rowd = rowd; this.cold = cold; }
    public Dir next() { return values()[(ordinal()+1) % values().length]; }
  }
  static final int rows = 4, cols = 6;
  static final int[][] grid = new int[rows][cols];
  static int row, col = -1, step;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    Dir dir = Dir.R;
    moving: while (true) {
      for (int i = 0; i < Dir.values().length; i++, dir = dir.next())
        if (move(dir)) continue moving;
      break;
    }
    for (int[] row : grid) System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
  }
  static boolean move(Dir dir) {
    final int newRow = row+dir.rowd, newCol = col+dir.cold;
    if (newRow >= 0 && newRow < rows && newCol >= 0 && newCol < cols
        && grid[newRow][newCol] == 0)
    {
      row = newRow; col = newCol; grid[row][col] = ++step; return true;
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Square Spiral**

Here is a compact solution in a single function that performs optimally (it only visits each location in the array *exactly* once):

```
static int anMoveXDir[] = { 1, 0, -1,  0 };
static int anMoveYDir[] = { 0, 1,  0, -1 };

static void DoSpiral(int *panGrid, int nWidth, int nHeight)
{
    int nSideSel, nSideIdx, nMoveDir, nXPosn, nYPosn, nCounter;
    int anSideLen[2];

    anSideLen[0] = nWidth;
    anSideLen[1] = nHeight - 1;

    nMoveDir = 0;     /* start off at (0, 0) in array, */
    nXPosn   = 0;     /* facing east, and count from 1 */
    nYPosn   = 0;
    nCounter = 1;

    for (nSideSel = 0; anSideLen[nSideSel & 1]; anSideLen[nSideSel++ & 1]--)
        for (nSideIdx = anSideLen[nSideSel & 1]; nSideIdx; nSideIdx--)
        {
            panGrid[(nYPosn * nWidth) + nXPosn] = nCounter++;

            if (nSideIdx == 1)
                nMoveDir = (nMoveDir + 1) & 3;

            nXPosn += anMoveXDir[nMoveDir];
            nYPosn += anMoveYDir[nMoveDir]; 
        }
}
```

This algorithm works on the simple rule that given a rectangular or square array of width `x` and height `y`, then the walking the array to create a Square Spiral can be done using the following number of steps:

```
x + (y - 1) + (x - 1) + (y - 2) + (x - 2) + (y - 3) + (x - 3) + ... + 0
```

The function above simply follows the above sequence. It starts at the top-left of the array facing east, walks `x` steps, turns right 90 degrees, walks `(y - 1)` steps, turns right 90 degress, walks `(x - 1)` steps, etc. etc. until either `x` or `y` is zero, whichever comes first.

You can test the function above by inserting it into the test program below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define GRID_WIDTH    7
#define GRID_HEIGHT  11

void main()
{
    int nXPosn, nYPosn;
    int anGrid[GRID_WIDTH * GRID_HEIGHT];
    int *pnValue;

    DoSpiral(anGrid, GRID_WIDTH, GRID_HEIGHT);

    for (pnValue = anGrid, nYPosn = 0; nYPosn < GRID_HEIGHT; nYPosn++, printf("\n"))
        for (nXPosn = 0; nXPosn < GRID_WIDTH; printf("%4i", *pnValue++), nXPosn++);
}
```

The output will be as follows (for a 7x11 grid as indicated in the above program):

```
 1   2   3   4   5   6   7
32  33  34  35  36  37   8
31  56  57  58  59  38   9
30  55  72  73  60  39  10
29  54  71  74  61  40  11
28  53  70  75  62  41  12
27  52  69  76  63  42  13
26  51  68  77  64  43  14
25  50  67  66  65  44  15
24  49  48  47  46  45  16
23  22  21  20  19  18  17
```